# NetworkManager applet looks like it can't see network

Tags: ubuntu-9.04, networkmanager

My system is Ubuntu 9.04.

There is NetworkManager applet, but it looks like there are no networks. When I click it, there is disabled menu "Wired Network/device not managed". I have working eth0 interface, internet is working fine and I can see eth0 in `ifconfig`

When I right-click and choose "Edit connections", there is only "Auto vboxnet0" under "Wired" tab. No "eth0".

It shouldn't be a problem, but I cannot connect to VPN because of this :(

Answer (score 1):

I've run into some similar issues recently with Fedora 11 as well.  You'll have to translate the following to Ubuntu.

I've found that restarting the NetworkManager daemon process (rather than the applet) sometimes helps.  I've also tried restarting the HAL daemon; but I think that caused problems due to an SELinux label being wrong.  (Had to do `restorecon -v nm-dhclient-eth0.conf` in `/var/run` at some point after that attempt.)

Currently running 2.6.30.8-64.fc11.i686.PAE kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I currently have a similar problem on Ubuntu 10.4 LTS. This is my home Desktop system, but I also use it with [KVM & libvirt](http://doc.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/serverguide/C/libvirt.html).

This is some sort of conflict between regular network interfaces (eth0) and interfaces for Virtualization (Bridged interfaces like br0, VirtualBox's interface like vboxnet0). It seems that Ubuntu's Network Manager doesn't play well on systems which have a Virtual Network interface, or a bridged interface. I've read that NetworkManager will hide certain interfaces in some situations, such as in [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/199140)

The only solution I've found so far is:

/etc/init.d/networking stop

And then right click on NetworkManager and select "restart" or "Start".